# Why aren't the Xindi referred to anywhere other than Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, timeline, xindi

The Xindi (multiple species in the sector) were shown only in *Enterprise*. What happens to them in the later timelines? Why isn't there any mention of these species in other Star Trek series, since Enterprise was prologue to all the other series?

(Apart from the simple logic that, since Enterprise was the last of the series, Xindi was thought of only then!)

Comment: Think your last sentence answers your own question :)

Comment: Are you asking if this inconsistency was retconned in some way?

Comment: If I were searching for an in-universe answer, it might be that since the Xindi were able to attack the Earth directly, all information on them would have been strictly classified. People on the ground may have never been given significant data beyond what they needed to know. (An alien has attacked the Earth, go back to your homes. StarFleet is handling this.) By the time Kirk and Company are heading into space, there have been wars with Romulans, increasing aggressions from the Klingons and greater effort keeping the wars AWAY from Earth.

Comment: There is an episode of TNG where Picard mentions a Xindi ambassador.  I'm not posting it as an answer because I can't recall _which_ episode, but my additional searching just now has me convinced it's not someone from, say, the Xendi Sabu system - he pronounces the two differently.

Comment: @izkata looks like thats as close as well get to xindi!

Comment: Because *Enterprise* never actually happened - it's revealed in the last episode that the whole thing was just a Holodeck game being played by Riker and Troi.

Comment: @Gaius - "And then Riker turns round in the shower and it turns out that JR's not dead and it was all just a dream"...

Comment: I thought Enterprise was a holodeck sim of real events? Am I wrong? Sort of like going back to watch the pyramids being constructed.

Comment: @Gaius I thought he was watching the thing as a historical representation? I haven't reached that episode yet, so I dunno

Comment: they probably fractured further and got different names

Comment: there are different kinds of Xindi, even 2 types of mammals: arboreals and mammals. there have been avians but they are extinct, then you have insectoids, aquatics and reptilians, but why weren't there any amphibious ones? why use most animal classes we know on earth and forget the amphibious?

Answer (score 12):

It's never been relevant to bring them up. I figure, look at it this way: We never heard about the Eugenics Wars until Space Seed; we never heard about the Post-Atomic Horror until Encounter at Farpoint; we never heard about the Federation being at *war* with the Cardassians until the fifth season episode The Wounded. These are all major events that are simply glossed over until they become relevant - the most egregious of these being the Federation-Cardassian War which has apparently been going on just off-screen of the Enterprise-D until peace is declared.

But the reason none of these seeming retcons matter is because: they weren't relevant to the characters at that time. The Fed-Cardassian War was irrelevant to the Enterprise-D's mission... until it was time to negotiate a peace, so the characters talk about it. The Post-Atomic Horror was never relevant to Kirk & co... but when Picard & co are transported to one of its courts, hey, its relevant to their day-to-day so its time to talk about it. The Eugenics War didn't matter to Spock, McCoy, Kirk, or Scotty until a superman was in their sickbay -- it wasn't part of their day to day life.

The Xindi aren't referenced because 100 years later, 200 years later, they're not vital to everyday life in Starfleet. It is 2014 and I don't bring up World War I all the time... sometimes? Sure, when it is relevant to something going on in my life, like if I'm talking about wars. The simplest solution, the most realistic solution, is that: just like we don't go around talking about Serbia and the death of Archduke Ferdinand all the time, nothing ever happened that made the characters feel the need to cite an event 100 years or 200 years before their time. Not when they could cite a more recent crisis, or an event in their more recent memory.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [Star Trek Wikia](http://star-trek.answers.wikia.com/wiki/In_Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_there_is_a_reference_to_the_Xindi_in_%27Xindi_Starbase_Nine%27._Does_this_mean_the_Xindi_are_members_of_the_Federation_by_the_time_of_ST:TNG), there is (supposedly) a reference to the [Xindi](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Xindi) in the opening log entry of TNG episode : "[The Battle](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/110.htm)" when Picard and crew are sent to the "Xendi / Sabu System" to rendezvous with a Ferenghi starship;

> **Picard Voiceover :** *Captain's log, stardate 41723.9. In response to a Starfleet order we are in the **Xendi/Sabu star system,** having
>   rendezvoused with a Ferengi vessel which has requested a meeting.
>   Although we arrived here and made appropriate signals to the Ferengi
>   three days ago, they have so far responded only with the message
>   "Stand by Enterprise".*

[image: Xendi/Sabu]

Later, Picard receives his old ship, the Stargazer and Data informs the bridge crew that a tug-ship stands ready to transfer their new possession to the nearest Federation outpost;

> **DATA:** *Starfleet has responded to our request, sir. A tug will rendezvous with us and tow the Stargazer back to Xendi Starbase Nine.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Very well, Data.*

I'll happily admit that can't find any official quote or reference to confirm that this is more than a fan theory based on a coincidental pronunciation. Also, the spelling in the official subtitles is **Xendi**, not Xindi.

Comment: Haha.. You've got answer to even this unanswerable one.

Answer (score 10):

The only in-universe explanation is that with such a huge pool of species to choose from, the Xindi that existed in the Federation during later *Star Trek* series just didn't happen to come across any of the characters in those shows. It's not without precedent; The Tholians didn't appear on-screen after the events of *The Tholian Web*, though they were mentioned. It was never ret-conned, at least not in any televised material. It is possible that a novel dealt with it.

Comment: Tholians did appear in the Enterprise two parter 'In a Mirror Darkly'.  And don't understand 'the Xindi that existed in the Federation during later Star Trek series ...'.  Since Enterprise was the last series, why would anyone expect that prior series writers would even have the notion of a species like the Xindi ?

Comment: *TOS* is after *Enterprise*, chronologically. Don't downvote things just because you misunderstand. And red the question; Binoj Antony specifically mentions the prior series. He's after an in-universe explanation.

Comment: I was being diplomatic and I did read the question.  I don't see any in-universe explanation.  As you state, it was never ret-conned and anything else is pure speculation.  Binoj answered himself with his last sentence.

Comment: There have been two in-universe explanations offered. Yes, they are speculative, but they are attempts at explaining this issue, which is more than can be said for your misunderstanding of both the question and my answer.

Comment: Well, we both have an opinion.  Mine is that any attempt to explain in-universe is speculation / opinion and thus, not an answer - conjecture only unless someone can point to a novelization that addresses.  Surprised the question wasn't put an hold as 'primarily opinion based'.

Comment: Unlike Tholian which was trivial (relatively), Xindi plot took up 24 Episodes of Season 3 and the last episode of season 2, hence I thought it must be important enough to be mentioned in subsequent timelines, I mean even andorians incidents have taken up lesser episodes that Xindi!

Comment: @stan: "any attempt to explain in-universe is speculation / opinion and thus, not an answer" - that's going to invalidate a lot of questions on this site. This isn't Stack Overflow. I think it's valid to have questions about in-universe stuff - sometimes works of fiction are unclear to some people, and answers here can make them clearer.

Comment: @PaulDWaite - No problem with the question per se but when an answer can't be backed up by any reference from material ... And in this particular case asking about why a species that appeared in Enterprise didn't appear in any prior produced series !!! As I said in my comment under the question, think Binoj answered it with his own last statement. Sometime folks look for answers to things that just don't exist. I still think answers to this one are opinion.

Comment: And you're still wrong. It's a legitimate question; unfortunately, all possible answers rely on conjecture (and I agree there may have been a better way to word the question so as to avoid that). But if you eliminate conjecture in answers, why does this site even exist? As I stated earlier, I provided a perfectly workable in-universe explanation. I would agree it is not entirely satisfactory, but it is based on in-universe events and therefore, while relying on supposition, does not rely merely on opinion. Richard also provided a possible answer using in-universe events some time after.

Answer (score 3):

You guys are missing something huge: the Xindi became a prominent species because somebody was messing with the timeline. Obviously, originally there was no Xindi threat they could have been destroyed it could've been conquer the could have killed themselves who knows. It's only because of the change in the timeline that enterprise even went the mission in the first place.

Comment: This is actually an important point.

Comment: I fully agree with this too, weve seen examples of stable time loops before, all that messing with time that happened during the war could of changed history or killed of the xindi (in the future: as in a natural disaster later that never should have happened)

Answer (score 0):

As I was watching  season 1 episode 7 of star trek the animated series, the Xindi are mentioned at 19:27 into the episode.

Comment: Close, but it's not 'Xindi'. Sounds more like 'Gazinty'. Perhaps it's meant to be 'Kzinti', as in episode 14's ('The Slaver Weapon') antagonists.

Answer (score -3):

If you want my backup you might try re-watching the series, while the Xindi thing may have been inaccurate it was a theory, and regardless its more than most people gave. Half these people have seen like maybe a series and call themselves Trekkies.

I don't devote myself to much, but star trek is my show and I watch it religiously. I make assumptions and theories the same as all of you but in fact the xindi weapon was fired as noted in s4 e3 when everyone is still up in arms about it after timeline reset from s4 e1&2 making my theory bunked, however the events of kirks time (20 years later) may still have altered the timeline in some way.

I'm busy watching it to discover the reset in the timeline but unlikely ill find it as Xindi were not mentioned anywhere else even googling Xindi Xendi and Zindy (looking for common misspellings) I only recovered one mention in star trek tng about a Xendi (not the same) space station and a small footnote where the Borg had a Xindi officer (by appearance only) on board a ship sometime during the Undine (species 8472) battles.

I can however only speculate (that means not a fact btw) that the Xindi became xenophobic after the events of the sphere builders and we haven't seen the last of them it would make a killer short series if not longer (like ds9) about the events that lead up to sphere builders battle 400 years later.

K so I mentioned my (self proven) false theory my new theory and personal belief that star trek is not a complete series yet and even though have a love for the universe as we know it lets wait and see what they bring into play from the mirror universe that may (or may not) alter the enterprise NX class missions everything will be answered in due time

just so everyone is aware "theoretically" does not mean i need fact to prove my theory i need events that lead me to that conclusion and if you were to sit and think long enough you'd speculate too but my answer still beats " didn't you pay attention the whole thing was a hologram that riker played...."

Comment: Please use sentences, proper capitalization, and split this up into paragraphs. As it is, it is unreadable.

Comment: reading through this, it seems like you have an answer buried in here amongst a lot of unnecessary chatter.

Comment: @phantom42 Other than the supposed footnote about a Xindi Borg appearing during Scorpion 1 or 2, there isn't much else in this answer. But if they can narrow down the rambling to just that and provide the source then it might be something.

Answer (score -5):

i wish to point out my theory and you can go all mad cow if you want on me but hear me out (or read whatever) so first off the thing i want to point out i that the whole thing was not a holodeck fantasy as stated by gaius but a recreation of its last mission in which he just interacts with the crew ok now onto important topics

1. the xindi species never attacked earth (in theory) because when the temporal war is finished shortly after the end of season 3 daniels takes archer up and shows him everything being repaired to its original timeline therefore (in theory) the sphere builders never gave the xindi any advice and the suliban never recieved any help either making for a complete rewrite being made possible
2. that being said they did ruin it by having everyone know about the attack after the timeline reset when only archer should have been aware of anything if even him.

i have watched this series 3 times i have alot of questions still but i hope this helps answer yours

Comment: Downvoted since this is basically fan-fiction. I look forward to your questions though. We don't have enough 'Enterprise' questions asked. ..

Comment: What @Richard said. As long as you cannot back up your claims with either quotes from episodes or extended canon such as books and comics in-universe - or claims from the producers supporting your theory out-of-universe, it is unlikely to get upvoted (which is not going *"mad cow"* on you btw, but the way SE works).

Comment: Please use capitals and full stops in your future questions.